# Trailhead Site Down?

Tags: error, trailhead

Anybody know why I would be seeing an Application Error for the Trailhead site?

[image]

Comment: Seems fine for me...try https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules instead.

Comment: Navigating to the modules is fine yes.

Comment: Ddos attack on East coast may be responsible? http://www.cnbc.com/2016/10/21/major-websites-across-east-coast-knocked-out-in-apparent-ddos-attack.html

Answer (score 2):

**Update** Looks like it's working again.

Just the home page seems to be down as far as I can tell. However, if I view the [Modules](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules) page (or any others I have tried) it works just fine.

I do get something a little more user friendly:

[image: 500 Tree Down On Trail]

I'm now getting a 404 on my profile as well, though it worked when I first checked after seeing your question.

[image: 404 Trail Not Found]

Comment: Receiving 500 now but just got Application Error in the beginning. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Also receiving a 404 error when navigating to my profile. Looks like SF are having some issues.

Comment: @TSmith I navigated to my profile first and it worked then. Now I'm getting a 404 there as well. And now I'm getting the `Application Error` home page. Looks like they're having some issues indeed.

Comment: All seems to be restored, time to Trailhead.